# All Sum Results under a single group by function as static conditions

Tags: mysql

**I'm trying to get the output as follows but don't understand how can I use all sum results under a single group by function as static conditions**

| Sum_Total_usage | Total_User |
| --- | --- |
| 0-100 | 60 |
| 101-300 | 40 |
| 301-500 | 20 |

**Following Static Conditional value will be the sum of FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS & FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS columns and also under conditional SESSION_START_TIME

- Between 0 AND 100
- Between 101 AND 300
- Between 301 AND 500
- Between 501 AND 800
- Between 801 AND Above

**Below Output is getting right now without condition:**

[image]

**Below is my table data:**

[image]

Below is my Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(usd.user_name) AS All_User,
ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) + ROUND((ROUND((SUM(usd.FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS)/1048576)))/1024,2) AS Total_Usage
FROM user_session_detail usd
WHERE usd.SESSION_START_TIME > '2022-02-01 00.00.01' AND usd.SESSION_START_TIME < '2022-02-01 03.59.59'
```

Comment: Show source data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, and desired output for this data. Especially-show where `conditions` column data should be taken from.

Comment: @Akina sample table data is attached here.

Comment: This is not sample table but a screenshot. Provide textual, code formatted CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Also - check your DBMS carefully. The datetime format on the screenshot is not valid in MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

you can use `group by case when condition < 101 then 1 when condition < 301 then 2 when condition < 501 then 3 when condition < 801 then 4 else 5 end` at the end

Comment: Where you have taken the column `condition` from? There is no such column in the sample data table.

Comment: The conditions were not specified by the OP, can be replaced with whatever is required as conditions.

Comment: @Akina There is no such column 'condition'. I just highlighted these conditions that will be needed to execute the query.

Comment: @Akina Total_Usage Alias is the sum of FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS and FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS. This sum result should come in between statement such as BETWEEN 0 AND 100, BETWEEN 101 AND 300 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Select conditions, sum(total_users) as users, sum(total_usage) as usage from(

SELECT total_users, total_usage,
case
when total_usage < 100 then 'less then 100'
when total_usage > 100 then 'more then 100'
else null
end as conditions
from user_session_detail
) b group by conditions
```

Comment: There is no such column 'condition'. I just highlighted these conditions that will be needed to execute the query.

Comment: @RaceTech Please read the code "end as conditions" This will present data in view column conditions

Answer (score 0):

None server can return the data which is absent on it. If the conditions values are absent then they must be created as a rowset. In CTE/subquery (dynamically, `SELECT 100 condition UNION SELECT 300 UNION ...`), or in specially created static table - it doesn't matter.

Schematically:

```sql
WITH 
userdata AS ( {the aggregate query which calculates amount per user} ),
conditions AS ( SELECT 0 AS min_value, 100 AS max_value UNION ALL
                SELECT 101, 300 UNION ALL
                ... 
                SELECT 801, 2147483647 )
SELECT CONCAT('Between ', conditions.min_value, ' and ', conditions.max_value) AS user_group,
       userdata.*
FROM userdata
JOIN conditions ON userdata.aggregated_value BETWEEN conditions.min_value AND conditions.max_value;
```

If MySQL version is 5.x and does not support CTEs then use subqueries.

PS. Pay attention - there is no restriction for the groups ranges in the conditions, they may be non-adjacent and/or overlap. In this case the user statistic will be categorized with all matched groups.

PPS. 2147483647 is maxvalue for INTEGER SIGNED. If the statistic have another datatype then adjust this constant value.

---

**UPDATE**

> Based on these conditions i will get the user_count. So my output will be showing the range in a row and the corresponding user_count. – RaceTech

```sql
WITH 
userdata AS ( {the aggregate query which calculates amount per user} ),
conditions AS ( SELECT 0 AS min_value, 100 AS max_value UNION ALL
                SELECT 101, 300 UNION ALL
                ... 
                SELECT 801, 2147483647 )
SELECT CONCAT('Between ', conditions.min_value, ' and ', conditions.max_value) AS user_group,
       COUNT(*) AS users_in_group
FROM userdata
JOIN conditions ON userdata.aggregated_value BETWEEN conditions.min_value AND conditions.max_value
GROUP BY user_group;
```

Comment: 0, 100, 101 .... these are not static values. These values will be the sum of FREE_UPLOAD_OCTETS and FREE_DOWNLOAD_OCTETS and will work as conditions. Based on these conditions i will get the user_count. So my output will be showing the range in a row and the corresponding user_count.

Comment: I have edited the question for your convenience. Pls check.

Comment: @RaceTech Add into the question: textual code-formatted sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (you may create online fiddle and provide a link); desired output for this sample data strictly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71335360/sum-results-in-having-clause-to-get-user-count

Comment: @RaceTech Do you understand the words "textual code-formatted"? Do you know the difference between the text and the picture?